# Sync content from my iPad to iTunes? i.e. "reverse" syncing

Tags: windows, itunes, ipad, sync

I recently had to reset my PC back to factory settings which lost my entire iTunes library. I still have my music and other files on my iPad and want to sync it back to the PC.

Upon syncing it only gives me two options. "Erase and Sync" which replaces the contents of my iPad with the blank iTunes library, or, "Transfer Purchases" which reads like it will only transfer the purchases from iPad to iTunes.

I would like to avoid re-burning my entire CD library to iTunes all over again. Is there a way for me to sync the iPad to the iTunes library (aka the computer)?

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly a better way, but try jailbreaking it (jailbreakme.com), then install netatalk (if you have a Mac) or open-ssh (for any OS) and copy the music back to your computer. It's in random orders and not tagged properly, but iTunes will probably work out what's what.

Perhaps back stuff up in future?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:)
Its not free but easiest way to do that do not lost your stuff
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=iv&v=LMsCgJubM18&annotation_id=annotation_20798

In the future, get external hard drive and save itunes library out of computer.

Hope its helps

Answer (score 0):

Cucusoft or ifunbox can access files on the IPad, then cycle the files to the computer and back. You can use Itunes to rename the files according to the music tags. That way, at least you don't lose the music when syncing, which will indeed only sync the Itunes purchases.